# Why are mmap syscall flags not set

Tags: system-calls, mmap, flags

I am trying to call mmap with a direct syscall.

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main() {
    __asm__("mov $0x0, %r9;"
            "mov $0xffffffffffffffff, %r8;"
            "mov $0x32, %rcx;"
            "mov $0x7, %rdx;"
            "mov $0x1000, %rsi;"
            "mov $0x303000, %rdi;"
            "mov $0x9, %rax;"
            "syscall;");
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the program statically:

```
$ gcc -static -o foo foo.c
```

But the syscall fails, as shown by strace:

```
$ strace ./foo
mmap(0x303000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
```

We can see that mmap flags are wrongly set. 0x32 should be MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED | MAP_ANONYMOUS.
The thing is, if I put another mmap call with mmap from the libc:

```
int main() {
    mmap(0x202000, 4096, 0x7, 0x32, -1, 0);
    __asm__("mov $0x0, %r9;"
            "mov $0xffffffffffffffff, %r8;"
            "mov $0x32, %rcx;"
            "mov $0x7, %rdx;"
            "mov $0x1000, %rsi;"
            "mov $0x303000, %rdi;"
            "mov $0x9, %rax;"
            "syscall;");
    return 0;
}
```

Then both mmap work:

```
$ strace ./foo
mmap(0x202000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x202000
mmap(0x303000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x303000
```

So it seems that using libc, mmap flags are "resolved" or something. But I can't really understand what is happening.

Why does the mmap syscall example only work if I put a libc mmap call before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel syscall interface on AMD64 uses `r10` register as a fourth argument, not `rcx`.

```
mov $0x32, %r10
```

See [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6) for more details.

Comment: That's it, thanks! And now I understand why it was working with the libc call before: r10 was set and didn't change between the two calls.